# simple JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript

```
myarray = [];

function elements(question, answer)
{
   this.question = question;
   this.answer = answer;
}

var newelement = new elements("1 + 1", "2");

myarray.push(newelement);
```

How can I retrieve "1+1" and "2" in the future, without using the numeric index?

Thanks a lot Stack Overflow!

Comment: what do you mean by numeric index.You don't want to use the array??this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

안녕하세요 지헤님.

If you put the object in an array, you will need to get it with an index.

```
myarray[n].question;
myarray[n].answer;
```

Of course, you could use a for loop to go through all of the objects and do something with them.

```
for (var c = 0, cl = myarray.length; c < cl; c++) {
  // do something with myarray[c];
}
```

Comment: what does the first line mean?

Comment: Just "Hello" and then her name.

Answer (score 0):

myarray[0].question
myarray[0].answer

Answer (score 0):

The only way to access elements in the array is via the index. It doesn't have to be a constant 0 or 1, and can be in a loop, but you have to in some way specify which index or the compiler wont know what you're referring to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here

Answer (score 0):

These are your options:

- `newelement.question` or `myarray[0].question`
- `newelement.answer` or `myarray[0].answer`

If you want to avoid the numeric index, you could loop over the array, or just use `newelement.question` / `newelement.answer`.

Answer (score 0):

How about '[for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)'. (New feature, so may not work in all browsers)

```
for (var el of myarray)
    console.log(el.question + " # " + el.answer);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of it, I'm going to treat "without using the numeric index?" as a riddle, of which I'll think of ways to solve...

Possible solutions to riddle:

- `var result = myarray.pop();`
- `var result = myarray.shift();`
- `var result; myarray.forEach(function(c) { result = c; });`
- `var result = myarray.reduce(function(a,c) { return c; });`